# Different My Site Themes on different SSP's

Tags: sharepoint, themes, mysite

We are running MOSS 2007, with 4 different SSPs.

I want to change the theme that is applied to the mysites created on one of the SSPs. I plan to do this using feature stapling but how can I deploy this feature to just this specific mysite url as it only differs by port number.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the feature Site / WebApplication scoped? That way you target only the web application / site-collection the feature is activated in...

Comment: But Site Stapling Feature should be Farm Scoped ?

Comment: Can be site-collection scoped as well, when i use feature stapling I set them on site collection level..

Comment: It seems that if I scope my stapling feature to WebApplication then when I addsolution > deploysolution I cant specify a -url parameter as it tells me that there is nothing targeting the web application scope. Is there a way round this?

Comment: That's weird, the solution should detect webapplication scoped features and then give the option to deploy to a specific url. I seem to recall that it needs some content to deploy to the web application / site collection as well (had this issue pop up once before also). could you add a feature that adds a dummy text file for test purposes to a site collection (Scope=site) and retest?

Comment: Aha, check out this link and answer below

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

[SharePoint+Features+-+Scope+of+Deployment](http://wiki.threewill.com/display/is/2008/10/02/SharePoint+Features+-+Scope+of+Deployment)

> The web application deployment target is used as the destination for the  following application scope resources which may appear in your solution manifest. These are physical changes to files within your web application  (IIS web site).

- ApplicationResourceFiles - Ex: MyFiles\My.resx. See the comment at the  bottom of the solution manifest schema for some more detail.
- Assemblies (if the DeploymentTarget is set to WebApplication) -> Ex:  [web]\80\bin\MyAssembly.dll
- CodeAccessSecurity - Changes to  section in  [web]\web.config to point to a new custom policy file in [12]\config
- DWPFiles - .webpart and .dwp files for custom web parts
- SafeControls - Additional entries in  section in  [web]\web.config.